# Line number inside line "lineno" package

Tags: numbering, counters, lineno

I have issue with this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}

\parindent=0pt
\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{-\arabic{linenumber}-}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
Text \thelinenumber\ text \\
Text \thelinenumber\ text \\
Text \thelinenumber\ text \par
Text \thelinenumber\ text 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Counter `linenumber` not increased within lines except  after `\par`, contrary to the line number shown on the left side of the page.

How I can display or use line number (for example in conditional) inside lines?

Comment: This is similar to other counters like `\thepage`, which is not fully known at the time of setting it. From the [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/ulineno.pdf): "Whenever you want to attach something to your text, *after a paragraph was broken into lines*, across pagebreaks, `lineno` may do the job." Since you're using ``\\`` to denote a line-break, the paragraph has not been broken into lines. This only happens with the occurrence of `\par` or a blank line. What about a `\label`-`\ref` to extract the correct number?

Comment: I want to use line number in conditional `\ifnum` like this 
`\ifnum\value{linenumber}=2  we are in the second line \fi`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For extracting the *ordinal* representation of a line number, you can set a `\linelabel` and retrieve it using a combination of regular `\getrefnumber` (from [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount); to avoid extracting it to a counter) and `\ordinalnum` (from [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno,refcount,fmtcount,xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{-\arabic{linenumber}-}
\renewcommand{\theLineNumber}{\arabic{linenumber}}

\newcounter{linecntr}
\newcommand{\ordinalline}{%
  \stepcounter{linecntr}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\linelabel{linecntr-\thelinecntr}}\x%
  \textcolor{red}{\ordinalstringnum{\getrefnumber{linecntr-\thelinecntr}}}}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dapibus 
facilisis magna, id sodales ante convallis vitae. In a porttitor nibh, 
We are in the \ordinalline{} line.
eget vehicula dui. Integer feugiat dui nec neque porttitor, non eleifend 
erat lobortis. Sed varius malesuada nisi, id vulputate ante commodo vitae. 
Nam non felis at ante mollis commodo eget porttitor ex. Donec in quam diam. 
We are in the \ordinalline{} line.
Maecenas fringilla, turpis a egestas pulvinar, massa lacus molestie enim, 
vel vulputate lorem ante ac velit. Nam ex nulla, venenatis et tortor at, 
We are in the \ordinalline{} line.
efficitur fringilla ante.

\end{document}
```