# Generate Automatic Labels in Lineno Package

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, line-numbering

I am trying to generate automatic labels to work with package `lineno`. For this, I defined a new counter `lineref` to work with the command `\linelabel` in the command `\linelabel{l\thelineref}`. The problem is that the command is not working, for one reason that I do not know, the reference is working just for the last generated label. Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{lineref}
\setcounter{lineref}{0}
\newcommand{\linemark}{\refstepcounter{lineref}\linelabel{l\thelineref}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{linenumbers}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit\linemark amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis magna in erat porta, nec posuere nisi gravida. Quisque tristique dui non ante rhoncus, eu cursus augue\linemark iaculis. Vivamus ut efficitur mauris, sed condimentum metus. Nullam in mattis tortor, nec\linemark blandit mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;\linemark Curabitur elementum sem nulla, nec sagittis enim mattis ac. Maecenas iaculis odio a erat dapibus,\linemark sed sagittis urna aliquam. Pellentesque et risus eu sem\linemark varius imperdiet ut non est. Ut facilisis quam et nibh convallis, ac rutrum magna faucibus.\linemark Pellentesque molestie tempus urna, in\linemark ultricies neque varius eget. Quisque id velit mattis,\linemark tincidunt turpis\linemark id, tempus sapien.
\end{linenumbers}

\par\getrefnumber{l1}
\par\getrefnumber{l2}
\par\getrefnumber{l3}
\par\getrefnumber{l4}
\par\getrefnumber{l5}
\par\getrefnumber{l6}
\par\getrefnumber{l7}
\par\getrefnumber{l8}
\par\getrefnumber{l9}
\par\getrefnumber{l10}
\end{document}
```

And here my output:

[image]

How can I get the correct number references??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332056/line-number-inside-line-lineno-package)

The trick is just to prevent the expansion of the command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{lineref}
\setcounter{lineref}{0}
%\newcommand{\linemark}{\refstepcounter{lineref}\linelabel{l\thelineref}}

\newcommand{\linemark}{%
  \stepcounter{lineref}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\linelabel{l\thelineref}}\x%
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{linenumbers}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit\linemark amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis magna in erat porta, nec posuere nisi gravida. Quisque tristique dui non ante rhoncus, eu cursus augue\linemark iaculis. Vivamus ut efficitur mauris, sed condimentum metus. Nullam in mattis tortor, nec\linemark blandit mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;\linemark Curabitur elementum sem nulla, nec sagittis enim mattis ac. Maecenas iaculis odio a erat dapibus,\linemark sed sagittis urna aliquam. Pellentesque et risus eu sem\linemark varius imperdiet ut non est. Ut facilisis quam et nibh convallis, ac rutrum magna faucibus.\linemark Pellentesque molestie tempus urna, in\linemark ultricies neque varius eget. Quisque id velit mattis,\linemark tincidunt turpis\linemark id, tempus sapien.
\end{linenumbers}

\par\getrefnumber{l1}
\par\getrefnumber{l2}
\par\getrefnumber{l3}
\par\getrefnumber{l4}
\par\getrefnumber{l5}
\par\getrefnumber{l6}
\par\getrefnumber{l7}
\par\getrefnumber{l8}
\par\getrefnumber{l9}
\par\getrefnumber{l10}
\end{document}
```